# What is the equivalent of the Run dialogue box in Windows for adding a printer?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, vpn

Using Ubuntu Focal Fossa on my laptop. This is the scenario.

My corporate laptop uses windows, and to use the printer, this is what I have to do.

1. Connect to the company VPN where the printer is connected.
2. Type `\\it-ufeoevr.shared-svivc.local` in the Run dialogue box that appears as part of the start menu
3. The printer (Cannon IR-ADV C55351) appears in any printer dropdown menu.

Now, I have been issued a laptop by my company for development purpose, where I use ubuntu. I can also connect to the VPN using it. But I cannot access the printer, even by trying to add it from the printer settings. I was wondering if there is any functionality in ubuntu similar to the run dialogue box in windows, or if my ubuntu laptop can *see* the printer at all.

Even my company IT is unable to help on this.

Answer (score 5):

There are two different questions.

1. Equivalent of Run dialog box
2. Installing a network printer

As for 2), you basically cannot install a network printer the way you do in Windows, which your corporate IT has told you. Linux is not Windows and you simply do configuration tasks in Linux in different way than in Windows.

You have to do it the regular way, by using Settings -> Printers -> Add printer, then you can enter the network address. Or it may be needed to add the printer via advanced settings (the button below), and specifying manually all printer details (I guess you will probably have to use the Windows Samba printer option). That's how I added printers long ago at my work computer, but it was a very old version of Ubuntu, where it was done a bit differently.

You need to try for yourself. Knowing all details of your printer will definitely help. If you can have access to a Windows computer with that printer already installed, it is possible you can view all the needed details there.

As for 1), you can either open a terminal (it's like opening command prompt window in Windows) and type the commands there (you can find terminal in applications menu or just press Ctrl+Alt+T), or if you want exact equivalent of "Run" dialog box, there is one, but I'm not sure if it works in GNOME Shell (that's Ubuntu's default DE, so it's probably the DE you are using) the same way as in GNOME Flashback, which I'm using. In my DE, you can press Alt+F2 to get the "Run" prompt.

Comment: My preferred method: cups webinterface  localhost:631   (631 is the default port)

Comment: @Riznwind command `cups` not found... Shell suggests `cupsd`, but `cupsd` does not accept the parameter `webinterface`

Comment: @raj Rinzwind is not suggesting that you run `cups webinterface localhost:631` as a command. They're talking about the web UI that CUPS runs which can be accessed by opening `http://localhost:631` in a browser

Comment: @muru Ah, I was too focused on the command line topic :) Stupid me.